# Ubuntu 17.04 only allows certain websites to be accessed

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet, wired, websites

Right after my upgrade to 17.04, my discord and steam immediately turned in and connected to the internet.  Assuming that the internet was fine, I booted up chrome, only to find certain sites unaccessible.  After some tinkering, I reinstalled 17.04 with the gnome desktop and tried the same thing but in Firefox.  In Firefox, I could access sites like Reddit and Google search, although these sites were somewhat slower than normal, but couldn't access sites like dl.google.com (where I tried to get the google-chrome-stable from) or the chrome website.  My connection is wired.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: it's pretty late, so I might not respond until tomorrow morning, so please forgive me.

Comment: I had problems after upgrading to 17.04 in that it couldn't find Google. In my case unplugging the router and modem helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Lubuntu 17.04 and Firefox. Websites affected included gmail, youtube, firefox sync.

I solved it by adding a DNS server manually in *Network Connections*. Find your connection in the *Network Connections* manager and edit it, go to the *IPv4 Settings*, and in *Additional DNS servers* write

```
8.8.8.8
```

which is a Google DNS server. After this, reconnect to your network and you should be able to access every website.